# Can we bring the distribution of the landing places of falling leaves from a tree bring in connection with some kind of attractor?

Tags: chaos-theory

I have already asked a few weeks ago if the motion of a falling leave is chaotic. Wich it is. But if we consider the collection of the trajectories of all the falling leaves, a pattern emerges on the ground. Can we bring this collection of all different paths (by seeing all the falling leaves as a whole and varying all the ways in which the leaves can fall from the tree) in connection with some kind of attractor, in which all the possible paths of a system as a whole that can develop (like the weather), are `attracted` to (or are part of) the infinite number of (obviously non-periodic) possible paths, which all together trace out the butterfly form? Wich means there is order in chaos.

Comment: Yes, a pattern is emerging.

Comment: Perhaps you are getting the downvotes because the questions in the body is too long.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no Lorenz attractor there. The trajectory of a particular falling leaf does not influence the trajectory of the next leaf that falls. (They are of course correlated, because they are both heavily influenced by the prevailing winds. But correlation does not imply causation.) Without this feedback, there is no chaos, only randomness.

Answer (score 0):

Leaves on most trees are arranged in a fractal pattern.  This pattern should influence their arrangement on the ground after they have fallen. The wind conditions during their fall (and the flutter nonlinearity) will also play a role in their final arrangement. Nevertheless I don't see how the Lorenz attractor plays any role.

Comment: There is no wind, and whoever the leaves fall, they are always converging to that same sort of pattern on the ground, wich is a sign of an attractor.

Comment: The fractal patterns of the leaves aren´t taken with the falling leaves.

Comment: Yes, it is the sign of an attractor but why would it be the Lorenz attractor?

Comment: I´ve changed that already.

Comment: @ Lewis Miller I can´t see how the fractal pattern of the leaves on the tree shows up in the distribution of the places where the leaves fall. The trajectories of the falling leaves are unpredictable, and for every little change in the falling conditions of the leaves, the same pattern emerges on the ground, in which no fractal patterns are seen.

Comment: All I'm saying is that the locations from which each leaf falls influences where they end up on the ground.  It is the collapse of a 3-D fractal onto a 2-D surface